# Moderator Tools and Flag Disagreement

Tags: discussion, flagging, 10k-tools

I was browsing the flags in the 10k tools this morning and noticed the "Flag or disagree" button on flags.

Diamond mods: on this site, do these help you or do they just add more flags to deal with?  I am especially talking about the autogenerated ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you disagree with the existing flag, or you flag the same post with a different flag, you are not adding more work for the moderators; you are helping the moderators.

That is particularly true with the automatic flags generated by the system.
A low quality flag generated automatically from the system doesn't say much; if to that you add a "not an answer" flag, the moderators know it is not an answer. An automatic flag generated because a user posted two answers that are the same doesn't say much, but a vote to close one of the questions because it is a duplicate, says more.

In short, automatic flags are a reason to check the flagged post; flagging a post that has an automatic flag, you are saying you checked the post, and found something that needs moderator's attention.